# How can get the value of text field by a alert view using Cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to develop a application by using Cocos2d. I can't getting value from textfield . How can get the value of text field (in a alert view) by using Cocos2d ?

```
-(void)timed1: (id)sender 
{
    UIAlertView* dialog = [[[UIAlertView alloc] init] retain];
    [dialog setDelegate:self];

    [dialog setTitle:@"Enter Time:"];
    [dialog setMessage:@" "];
    UITextField * nameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 45.0, 245.0, 25.0)];
    [dialog addSubview:nameField];
    [nameField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    CGAffineTransform moveUp = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 70.0);
    [dialog setTransform: moveUp];
    [dialog setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Done"];
    [dialog show];

    nameField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    nameField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
    nameField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    nameField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;

        //  timeStatus is a int type global variable
    timeStatus =[nameField.text intValue]; // this line not working i can't getting value namefield


    [dialog release];
    [nameField release];

}
```

Comment: Please how you solved this? I have the same problem: applicaion main window will create on button new window with text field but I can't access it's contents in main window then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Action sheets and alerts are handled asynchronously. In your case, the message [dialog show] merely schedules the show event for some later execution (handled by the main run loop). If you put in a few NSLog()s, you'll see that the [show] message returns almost immediately, at which point your user hasn't entered any data, nameField's text is blank, and this converts to an int of 0.

You want a blocking, modal dialog with input -- action sheets and alerts are not designed for user input beyond yes/no/cancel button pushes. You'll have to cook up a view of your own: not too hard, but it will require more work than using an action sheet/alert.